# Eliminating $\mu$ for variance answer

Tags: variance, expected-value

In a problem, I'm trying to find the variance, where $V[x]= E[(x- E[x])^2]$ and one of the things that I know is that $E[x]= \mu$, but my final answer cannot contain $\mu$. What information are you suppose to know/use to be able to substitute something in for $\mu$ so that it can be eliminated?

Comment: What information do you have?

Comment: $\mu=E(x)$ is the only relevant substitution (what else would it be?).  If you have a way to evaluate the expectation use that. Otherwise, since  $V(x)=E((x-\mu)^2)=E(x^2)-\mu^2$, therefore it *will* contain such a term *unless* cancelled by $\mathsf E(x^2)$.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it's part of a two component normal mixture?